# ios - transform UITableView cell under other cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, transform

I have an idea to animate/transform UItableview cell under others, I did an animation so you can imagine how i mean that...

[image]

Is that possible? I try to transform that cell, but it allways goes over others cells when I use

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 100);
```

Is possible to do what I want? Thanks for reply!

Comment: Is this realted to JQuery?

Comment: No, it isn't, that was mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only way which works for me is quite simple. I just set

`cell.clipsToBounds = YES;` and `cell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;`

and than, I can change frame of view to be out of bounds of cell :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a custom cell?

You need to implement UITableViewCell class, and to draw the assets using

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

This article can help you:  http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

When it done, you can add a simple animation to redraw your cell:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{

     //your new custom view

  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

  }
```